# Changing MS Access Control box with WinAPI

Tags: ms-access, winapi, vba

In an Access form control box, there are only 5 elements. From left to right: application icon, title, minimize, maximize and close.

Using VBA to call Access properties, it is impossible to alter this control box in a way that adds additional elements. My goal is to use a Win32 API call to add a question mark to this control box, which points to a webpage (url destination is specific for each form). I believe this is possible, because there are many Windows forms outside of Access that have this question mark in what is the equivalent of a control box.

Here's a cropped image of one of my forms illustrating what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Here's an image of a form from Word that has the question mark, leading me to believe it's possible:

[image]

I've spoken to one other person who told me he thought this was possible, but had no idea how. I've scoured the Internet trying to find anybody talking about it, but there's nothing.

Any advice?

Comment: It's not what you want but as an alternative I've used Help Scribble (https://www.helpscribble.com/vba.html) in the past. You can assign the F1 key to your forms to open help pages which might be another option for you.

Comment: I just made borderless windows and had my own controls. much simpler than fiddling with apis :)

Answer (score 2):

The question mark is created by giving a window the `WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP` [extended window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx), or the `DS_CONTEXTHELP` [dialog box style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729172.aspx):

> WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP
>   0x00000400L
>
> **The title bar of the window includes a question mark. When the user clicks the question mark, the cursor changes to a question mark with a pointer. If the user then clicks a child window, the child receives a [`WM_HELP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774305.aspx) message**. The child window should pass the message to the parent window procedure, which should call the [`WinHelp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762267.aspx) function using the `HELP_WM_HELP` command. The Help application displays a pop-up window that typically contains help for the child window.
>
> **`WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP` cannot be used with the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` or `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` styles**.

> DS_CONTEXTHELP
>
> Note that `DS_CONTEXTHELP` is only a placeholder. When the dialog box is created, the system checks for `DS_CONTEXTHELP` and, if it is there, adds `WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP` to the extended style of the dialog box.

Window styles are applied when a window is created with the `CreateWindow/Ex()` or `DialogBox... ()` function, or by using `SetWindowLong/Ptr()` on an existing window.

Comment: Thanks.
So it seems if I implemented that I wouldn't be able to keep the maximize and minimizze buttons since they can't be used in conjunction with WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP ?